# Class or variable not found: INF.classes.com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeConstants

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

My class path looks like below in jar and trying to load class in JMeter BeanShell Sampler and my java version is Java8 but getting error

C:\Jars\saturn-event-bridge-1.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\com\rbs\ccr\saturn\eventbridge\constants\

Beanshell script:

```
package BOOT-INF.classes.com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeConstants;
EventBridgeConstants constant = new EventBridgeConstants();
a=constant.toString();
System.out.println(a);
```

But when i run script in Jmeter version 3.2 getting below error

Error:
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``package BOOT-INF.classes.com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeCon . . . '' : Class or variable not found: INF.classes.com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeConstants

Is my script is correct for loading java class in JMeter. Please help here

Can you help me resolving issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `saturn-event-bridge-1.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` and all its dependencies if any to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation or amend [user.classpath property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) to point to the folder where your .jars are located
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar(s) up
3. Change first line to look like:

   ```
   import com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeConstants;
   ```
4. Your script should start working normally

Also consider:

1. Migrating to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with Groovy as Groovy [is the recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. Upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page as [it's recommended to use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)

Comment: Step1 : I already copied jar into JMeter /lib folder     Step2: Restarted JMeter  Step3:  Added import instead of package but getting exception like      "Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import BOOT-INF.classes.com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeCons . . . '' Encountered "BOOT -" at line 1, column 8. "

Comment: JMeter able to find class which is exist in default package but not able to find class in custom package

Comment: If you're not able to copy and paste a single line of text unfortunately I'm not able to help you further

Comment: Here is my code    'import BOOT-INF.classes.com.rbs.ccr.saturn.eventbridge.constants.EventBridgeConstants;
EventBridgeConstants constant = new EventBridgeConstants();
a=constant.toString();'
System.out.println(a);